# making + operator a part of an equation instead of string joiner

Tags: java

I've just picked up Java a few weeks ago and ran into this problem:

```
System.out.print("Please enter the #" + i + 1 + " data: ");
```

Currently, the output of the code is "Please enter the #01 data: ", instead of "Please enter the #1 data: ". How do I make it so that the + operator between i and 1 adds both of them together, instead of joining the string?

Comment: `+` is left-associative. So, `a + b + c + d` is evaluated as `((a + b) + c) + d`.

Answer (score 2):

Add parenthesis to clarify your intent:

```
System.out.print("Please enter the #" + (i + 1) + " data: ");
```

Alternatively you can [use `printf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintWriter.html#printf(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...)) to avoid manual string concatenation entirely:

```
System.out.printf("Please enter the #%d data: ", i+1);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you add the + sign to the string it will append to the existing String value. if you want to print the actual value then create a new variable for the adding the values then use that variable.

e.g.

```
int j = i +1;
System.out.print("Please enter the #" + j + " data: ");
```

Go through following link to understand more about the String concatenation

https://www.javatpoint.com/string-concatenation-in-java

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your int into ( i + 1)

```
System.out.print("Please enter the #" + (i + 1) + " data: ");
```

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer has already explained the solution, let me explain the reason. Since multiple + signs are used as the concatenation, and the same plus signs obviously follow the operating principle, that is, add them in order from right to left. In Java, a string + an integer is automatically converted to a string. So the result of "#01" appears.
When you use # + (i + 1), the operation priority is changed so that the priority of i + 1 is higher than the right.